# Python Threadpool not running in parallel

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and I am trying to use threadpool to run this script in parallel. However it does not run but just run in sequence. The scrip basically iterate through excel file to pick the ip address of devices and then sends xml request based on an input file. I have spent multiple hours on this, what am I not getting.

```
def do_upload(xml_file):
for ip in codecIPs:
    try:
        request = open(xml_file, "r").read()
        h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
        h.add_credentials(username, password)
        url = "http://{}/putxml".format(ip)
        print('-'*40)
        print('Uploading Wall Paper to {}'.format(ip))
        resp, content = h.request(url, "POST", body=request,
                              headers={'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8'})
        print(content)

    except (socket.timeout, socket.error, httpexception) as e:
            print('failed to connect to {}'.format(codecIPs), e)



pool = ThreadPool(3)
results = pool.map(do_upload('brandinglogo.xml'), codecIPs)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has no parallelism in its threading model due to the so called Global Interpreter Lock. Basically, all threads run on core only. It enables concurrent execution though. So for IO bound tasks, like downloading files from the web, database accesses, etc. You will get some speedup using threads to kick off those syscalls. But for CPU bound tasks, you need to use Processes. Therefore use the multiprocessing python library.